# Symfony 3 - need to setup VirtualHost?

Tags: php, virtualhost, symfony, virtual-hosts

I have some very basic question about Symfony and VirtualHost.

I have my **Symfony3 installed in *E:/XAMPP/htdocs/icp***

Everywhere i read, to setup VirtualHost, so I did it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
DocumentRoot "E:/XAMPP/htdocs/icp/web/app_dev.php"
ServerName icp.com
```

When I now call *icp.com* in the browser, the project renders, but in the background the browser can't find the referenced CSS-files **(no-route error)**.

When I delete the VirtualHost-entry and call the project via **localhost/icp/web/app_dev.php**, everything works finde.

My question now is, do I really need VirtualHost for local development?
If not, how would I call a route/controller(?),.. i.e. **ipc.com/mycontroller/mymethod/3** without VirtualHost??

Further there is the question, what did I wrong with my VirtualHost-config ??

Comment: [Read the manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do I really need VirtualHost for local development?**

It all depends on personal preference, if you want to open project with virtual host you can configure it like this if not keep like this **localhost/icp/web/app_dev.php**.

---

**What did I wrong with my VirtualHost-config ??**

You have issue in following line,

```
DocumentRoot "E:/XAMPP/htdocs/icp/web/app_dev.php"
```

DocumentRoot should not be pointing to `file`, instead it should point to `web` folder. Like this,

```
DocumentRoot "E:/XAMPP/htdocs/icp/web/"
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much :) .. after weeks of trying it finally works, but some of my work suddenly doesn't work..  what's about, wenn I would not like to use VHosts. How would I call a url mentioned in the question?  .. further, how would I need to configure it, so i get the **dev** ?

Comment: You can configure it in `.htaccess` file placed in web folder.